# Why did Jack lick the Rock?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean

In Davey Jones' Locker, we see Jack battling with himself, perhaps trying to stay sane, or just simply having fallen victim to the madness already.

However, after jumping off the Back Pearl, he finds a rock. He interacts with the rock a bit, throwing it, only to find it promptly return, then eventually picks it up, and licks it.

[image]

We soon discover that the rock(s) are actually crabs, (which we know are [linked to Calypso](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/218788/could-jack-sparrow-escape-from-davy-jones-locker-on-his-own/218789#218789)), and are Jack's ticket out of The Locker.

Jack is a smart man, in almost every aspect when it comes to the sea, especially when it comes to how things work with the monsters and magicks, so was there something going on in his head to realize that the rocks were not part of his "torment" in The Locker?

Comment: Well the simplest answer is [widens eyes and waggles fingers at like Capt. Jack], really.

Comment: A smooth rock is unlikely to harm you if you lick it, but you may lean something about what it is by taste.

Comment: Geologists were known as "rock-lickers" at my university. :D You can identify some by taste and feel on your tongue (porous ones will stick).

Comment: he's shown to be even more out of his mind than usual so just basic crazy delirium is one option. Also - he had previously just said the word 'lick' in relation to there not being even the tiniest gust of wind so there may be some word association there and he's using the rock as a kind of salt-lick to look for some nutrients in the wasteland (considering he's "killed" over a peanut)

Comment: He doesn't do it in the script or the novelisation (he just inspects it and throws it). I'm guessing it was a Depp ad-lib, just him being mad.